# What weapon combinations keep my biotic cooldowns at 200%?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm heavily oriented toward biotic usage, so my current loadout consists of only my pistol and SMG.  There are some occurrences, though, where I wish I had my sniper rifle or shotgun with me.  Factoring in all the available weight reduction mods and all classes' weight capacities, what combinations allow me to keep biotic cooldowns at 200%?

Comment: You should specify your class, different classes have different weight capacity.

Comment: @kotekzot I was hoping for an answer that covers all the classes as well, so each class doesn't require a separate question.  I'm playing an engineer, though

Comment: Ah, I assumed "my" referred to a specific character.

Comment: fyi I haven't forgotten to update my answer yet, I plan to eventually put out a detailed answer involving base level weapons, level 5 weapons, and level 10 weapons

Comment: @yx. I didn't doubt it, I was just going through my unaccepted questions.  Thanks!

Comment: I haven't found any better weapon combinations with level 5 weapons, its taking me a while to get to level 10 weapons since I'm mostly playing multiplayer these days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, with my vanguard, the best loadout I can carry is this combination:

1. M-3 Predator V pistol
2. M-4 Shuriken V with -60% weight mod
3. M-15 Vindicator V

This combination keeps my recharge speed maxed at 200%.  This is with the +35 weight capacity upgrade taken at Rank 5 Assault Mastery.

If I swap out the Predator for a M-77 Paladin V then my recharge speed drops to 196%

I might be able to improve this in a New Game+ by upgrading the weapons even further, but on my current run this seems to be the best I can do.

Combination #2 if you prefer sniper rifles:

1. M-97 Viper V (for more damage, M-92 Mantis V gets you 189% recharge)
2. M-4 Shuriken V with -60% weight mod

I'll keep you updated if I find lighter weapons.

Answer (score 0):

Best load out for Vanguard weapon wise if your going biotic are:
-Disiple Shotgun leveled to the max, with Shreeder, and melee upgrade. 
-Paladin Pistol with barrel, and pierce mod.
-Tempest SMG with lightweight, and mag upgrade.

If your Assualt Mastery is maxed out with weigh capacity selected you will be at 200% biotic efficiency with these three weapons.

Best armor to use is the Terminus Armor since it ups your shields, Melee strengh, and ammo capacity, all are huge for a biotic charge happy vanguard.

*leveled to the max does not ultimitely mean level 10 I've leveled to 5 and still was at 200% biotic ability.