# Do melee mods increase biotic charge damage?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In Mass Effect 3 multiplayer, do melee modifications affect/increase the biotic charge damage?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, melee damage does **not** affect biotic charge damage. You better upgrade charge itself to increase its damage (and other benefits).

Here you have a nice guide: [How do I use biotic charge effectively?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53614/how-do-i-use-biotic-charge-effectively)